# How do you ban a user from posting to your CQ5 blog?

Tags: adobe, aem

Apologies if I'm missing something here, but is it possible to ban a user from posting to a blog?

Is there a way to integrate with something like toolator or similar?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support.

Comment: This is not a tech support question. It's a confirmation as to whether there is functionality buried somewhere that I have completely missed before we run off and implement our own solution.There is functionality to remove an individual post, but not to ban users in general as far as I can tell. There are other integration points existing for spam and profanity filters, as well as process steps that exist. Failing a missed out of the box piece of functionality, we are planning to implement a custom process step, and integrate with something like toolator. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about banning the end users to comment on a blog which is on publish server ? Are you capturing the user's email ID and name before commenting ? If yes you might have to reverse replicate all the comments and their respective username and email,  further provide author to determine which all they want to block this could be achieved through many ways, one way could be a participant step with workflow to approve the comments. Once these are approved prepare a list of users need to be blocked and publish them. Add the logic in your comment so that the user not in the banned list can only comment. These are just my thoughts for now. Hope this helps you to get some direction. Putting here as an answer rather than comment since cannot add it in comments its too long.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. There are several ways to approach this programatically. What I'm double checking is that there isn't an option lurking somewhere in the system to do it. As no-one has commented in some time, I think it's fairly safe to assume that this is the case.